# Only the first video clip I drag to timeline has audio

Tags: premiere

Running premiere pro on windows 10.

I'm importing 3 videos into my project. When my timeline has nothing in it, the first video I drag in will have audio. However, the second one will never bring in the audio with it. This is the case even if I'm dragging the same clip twice. If I delete all clips and the project clip that shows up at the bottom of the media pane (forgive my lack of terminology) then I can drag another video and have it show up with audio.

The only solutions I've found involve deleting the cache file in appdata, which does nothing for me. I don't know what triggers this problem, or how this could possibly be desirable behavior. What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this before with camcorder clips. It was a bug in the codec used for avchd files. The workaround was to extract the audio with Adobe encoder,  and add it separately. I have not seen this since spring 2017. You might see if your deployment is up to date.